# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<li class="ql-item linkid175902">
   <a href="https://www.sitevi.com/#newsletter" class="btn-primary" target="_self" onclick="return xt_click(this,'C','','::newsletter','N')">
      <span class="txt-btn">newsletter</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

And I have this jQuery function to display my newsletter form:

```
function(n) {
    var t = n(".newsletter-form"),
        i = n(".linkid175902 .btn-primary"),
        e = n("<div />").text("Close").addClass("btn-close").click(function(n) {
            n.preventDefault(), t.hide().removeClass("is-open")
        });
    t.find(".nf-main-content").prepend(e), t.click(function(t) {
        n(t.target).hasClass("is-open") && e.click()
    }), i.click(function(n) {
        n.preventDefault(), t.show().addClass("is-open"), t.find(".nf-form-input input").focus()
    })
}(jQuery);
```

I have put [XiTi](http://www.xiti.com/en) on my website and every time I activate XiTi, jQuery throws me this error at line 1:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://www.sitevi.com/#newsletter at Function.ga.error (js:1) at ga.tokenize (js:1) at ga.select (js:1) at Function.ga [as find] (js:1) at n.fn.init.find (js:1) at n.fn.init (js:1) at n (js:1) at n.fn.init.$.fn.smoothscrollTo (js:273) at HTMLAnchorElement. (js:274) at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (js:1)

I tried to change the href of the link, but it doesn't change anything.  However, when I deactivate XiTi in my website, everything works goods.

Thanks

**EDIT :**

If I activate XiTi : there is 4 javascript steps when I click in the console and the execution in this order :

- The onclick attribute of my  element, which is XiTi analytics :

  `(function(event){return
  xt_click(this,'C','','::Newsletter_subscription','N') })`
- jQuery 2.1.4 (**when this line is executed, it will prints the syntax error**) :

  `(g=r.handle)||(g=r.handle=function(b){return typeof
  n!==U&&n.event.triggered!==b.type?n.event.dispatch.apply(a,arguments):void
  0})`

At this step, the error is printed in the console by this exact line :

```
n.event.dispatch.apply(a,arguments)
```

*n* is **jQuery**,

*n.event* is `Object {global: Object, add: function, remove: function, trigger: function, dispatch: function…}`

*n.event.dispatch* is `function (a){a=n.event.fix(a);var b,c,e,f,g,h=[],i=d.call(arguments),j=(L.get(this,"events")||{})[a.type]||[],k=n.event.special[a.type]||{};if(i[0]=a,a.delegateTarget=this,!k.preDispatch||k.preDispatch.call(t…`

*n.event.dispatch.apply* is `function apply() { [native code] }`

I tested `n.event.dispatch.apply()` which printed this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery214010396479065249409'
>   of undefined
>       at Object.fix (js:1)
>       at dispatch (js:1)
>       at eval (eval at r.handle (js:1), :1:18)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (js:1)

And finally, `n.event.dispatch.apply(a,arguments)` prints the syntax error.

- The xiti function which triggered clicks :

`function xtR(e) {}`

- Then, jQuery again:

`(g=r.handle)||(g=r.handle=function(b){return typeof n!==U&&n.event.triggered!==b.type?n.event.dispatch.apply(a,arguments):void 0})`

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think the error is being generated by the code you've provided. Does the error give a line number?

Comment: what is `xt_click`?

Comment: evolutionxbox > Yes, the line number is js:1. The first line, which is : 

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://www.sitevi.com/#newsletter
    at Function.ga.error (js:1)
    at ga.tokenize (js:1)
    at ga.select (js:1)
    at Function.ga [as find] (js:1)
    at n.fn.init.find (js:1)
    at n.fn.init (js:1)
    at n (js:1)
    at n.fn.init.$.fn.smoothscrollTo (js:273)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (js:274)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (js:1)`

Comment: epascarello > It's my Xiti tracking. A google analytics app like. It does'nt produce this error. The error is throwed by jQuery (js:1)

Comment: Can you provide a functional example (either here in a snippet or on jsfiddle)?